# Autocomplete current environment

Tags: environments, texniccenter, auto-completion

Is there a keyboard shortcut in TeXnicCenter to complete the current environment? In other words, it should add the appropriate `\end{....}`.

Comment: Press `Ctrl` + `Space`.

Comment: Have a look at [Tips on code completion on TeXnicCenter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2079/tips-on-code-completion-on-texniccenter).

Comment: @Gonzalo, @Stefan: I don't think either of your hints is what he's looking for. Imagine you have `\begin{pumpkinpie} Tralala` and now want to end the `pumpkinpie` environment. @Jeremy's looking for a keyboard shortcut that inserts `\end{pumpkinpie}` at this point, or whatever environment might've been begun last. I don't know of any such feature, at least not in version 1RC1.

Comment: @doncherry: in that case, I'll recommend to always type `\begin{<env>}` `\end{<env>}` at once (and in this circumstances auto completion can be handy), and fill the contents afterwards; this helps to prevent forgetting to end an environment.

Comment: [Obligatory emacs answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20843/215): `C-c ]` closes the current environment.

Comment: You might have more luck on a TeXnicCenter mailinglist or forum.

Comment: @Gonzalo I'd suggest you write up your comment as an answer. I can't imagine there is a better answer forthcoming...

Comment: Sadly, it does seem that the correct answer is "there isn't". Oh well. It's the main feature I miss from Emacs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Summarising comments as an answer, so that this question is 'answered'.)

It seems that you are looking for a keyboard shortcut to take the input

```
\begin{pumpkinpie}
  Tralala
```

and have TeXniccenter automatically close the environment with

```
\end{pumpkinpie}
```

(*i.e.* to close whatever the last environment opened was.) At present, the answer is 'TeXniceenter does not have such a function'. Perhaps lodge a feature request.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked this as the accepted answer. I've filed a feature request (https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3371679&group_id=36323&atid=479426) in case anyone else is interested.

Comment: Since the feature request above was closed by mistake, I filed a new one : http://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/1490/ . posting it here as it is one of the top google results

Comment: I know it's been a while since this question was posted, but as a frequent user of TexnicCenter just wanted to ask if someone knows any update about it? I was just thinking on switching to some other editor but I'm so used to this one that makes the decision hard! thanks!